# flutter horizontal list view

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I would like to create a horizontal scrollable component in flutter that has 3 vertical element.  [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show code, progress, what you tried, etc

Comment: Thank you Mariano for your quick response, I haven't started yet and I'm looking for some idea.

Comment: Then StackOverFlow is not the site for those requests. You could try on Reddit, searching libraries on Pub Dev or even Slack communities and Twitter. Here is to help you with issues in your code and implementations you can't get right, etc and not to request libraries, ideas, full code implementations, etc

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I made it with a slightly strange method, I hope it will be useful.

I'm just doing this because I enjoy doing it.

Good Luck

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int rowCount = (items.length ~/ 3) + (items.length % 3 != 0 ? 1 : 0);
    var x = List.generate(rowCount, (i) => List.generate(3, (j) => 0, growable: false), growable: false);

    int ind = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0 && j == 3 || ind >= items.length) {
          x[i][j] = -1;
        } else {
          x[i][j] = ind;
          ind++;
        }
      }
    }
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    title: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Trending",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "See All",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lime),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4,
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 1, mainAxisExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, crossAxisSpacing: 0, mainAxisSpacing: 0),
                        itemCount: (items.length ~/ 3) + (items.length % 3 != 0 ? 1 : 0),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => LayoutBuilder(
                          builder: (p0, p1) => Column(
                            children: [
                              if ((x[index][(index + 0) % 3]) != -1)
                                ItemRowWidget(
                                  model: items[x[index][(index + 0) % 3]],
                                  p1: p1,
                                ),
                              if ((x[index][(index + 1) % 3]) != -1)
                                ItemRowWidget(
                                  model: items[x[index][(index + 1) % 3]],
                                  p1: p1,
                                ),
                              if ((x[index][(index + 2) % 3]) != -1)
                                ItemRowWidget(
                                  model: items[x[index][(index + 2) % 3]],
                                  p1: p1,
                                ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  final List<ItemModel> items = [
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The 1",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The 2",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay"),
    ItemModel(
        imageUrl: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset-picture-id1322277517?k=20&m=1322277517&s=612x612&w=0&h=ZdxT3aGDGLsOAn3mILBS6FD7ARonKRHe_EKKa-V-Hws=",
        title: "Beat The Odds",
        subtitle: "Lil Tjay")
  ];
}

class ItemRowWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemRowWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.model,
    required this.p1,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ItemModel model;
  final BoxConstraints p1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 10.0,
          ) +
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 15),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: p1.maxHeight / 4,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: Image.network(
                model.imageUrl,
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 16,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  model.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 12,
                ),
                Text(
                  model.subtitle,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            const Icon(
              Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
              color: Colors.white54,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemModel {
  final String imageUrl;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  ItemModel({required this.imageUrl, required this.title, required this.subtitle});
}
```

Comment: Please, do NOT send the users to other websites in order to get their answers. Answers MUST be 100% resolved inside StackOverFlow. You can post code here without issues.

Comment: Thank you @rasityilmaz. It's exactly what I want.